# Codeigniter Image Upload PathInfo Extension 'The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am uploading multiple images and I need to get their different file format.
But the problem is i only got the first file image format and there's an error when I do resize images because of the incorrect file format.

I am having an error `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.` which occur when I put the `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` when getting file.

Here's my code

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count_upload; $i++) { 

            $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = pathinfo($_FILES['product_image']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $_FILES['product_image']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $_FILES['product_image']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $_FILES['product_image']['size'][$i];


            $file_name = $file_name;
            $config = array(
                'file_name'     => $file_name,
                'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png',
                'max_size'      => 3000,
                'overwrite'     => TRUE,
                'encrypt_name'     => FALSE,
                'remove_spaces'     => TRUE,
                'upload_path'
                =>  $directory
                // =>  './assets/img/products'
            );



            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $response = array(
                    'status'      => false,
                    'environment' => ENVIRONMENT,
                    'message'     => $error['error'],
                    'csrf_name'   => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
                    'csrf_hash'   => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
                );
                echo json_encode($response);
                die();
            }else {
                $file_name = $this->upload->data()['file_name'];
                echo $file_name;
                echo '<br>';
```

Comment: You need to specify field name when uploading a file - `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')`

Comment: @sauhardnc it's working i upload multiple image with the same file format when i remove the PATHINFO_EXTENSION

Comment: $_FILES['userfile']['name'] expects the name of the file so if you're sending extension of the file, naturally, it will result in an error. But if you insist on using `pathinfo()`, (I don't know why anyone would do that) you can use `pathinfo($_FILES['product_image']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_BASENAME)` which will return the name of the file.